# How to get current android's user info?

Tags: java, android, user-profile, owner

Android 4.2.1, having two system user accounts: owner + created user.
Trying to get current user's info:

```
final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

When the current user is owner, I'm getting empty result, when the current user is not the owner - everything works fine: there is an ID and correct DisplayName.

So, the question is: how can I get information about the current android's user? And how can I get all users?

Just to make it clear: users aren't expected to enter their google account, etc.

Comment: how did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I didn't :( If You have some thoughts or possible solutions to share, I would appreciate that.